# Lost my credentials, but I still have my .rdp file

Tags: remote-desktop, passwords, password-recovery

So I have an AWS instance, it's a t1.micro that's running some lightweight mysql stuff for me.   I have always just logged in with the .rdp file that I tossed on my desktop.   I, like an idiot, discarded / lost the pem file a while back and can no longer find it.

So that rdp file has a password saved in it / somewhere on my computer.   How do I get it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/remote_desktop_password.html

It will display your password.

Comment: Is it safe? when i try to open it windows say it contains virus or unwanted software.